# Issue with admin static files in Django 3 (Ubuntu, Nginx, Gunicorn, SSL)

Tags: django, nginx

I using Django 3.* for my project and everything works fine since I've installed SSL from Let's Encrypt by Certbot and since then I have an issue with serving static files in my admin.

[image]

My Nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name casekam.ru www.casekam.ru;
    
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/gleb/casekam/django_shop/django_shop/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/gleb/casekam/django_shop/django_shop/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/casekam.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/casekam.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/casekam.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.casekam.ru) {
        # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        return 301 https://casekam.ru$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = casekam.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name casekam.ru www.casekam.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Can't figureout where am i wrong. Will be appriciate for any hints and tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to

```
# if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```